# Jacoco test reports not generated in Guidewire

Tags: guidewire, gosu, gunit

We are using Guidewire version 9.0.5 and implementing the Jacoco plugin. We followed instructions from the Guidewire community on this from https://community.guidewire.com/s/article/How-to-Implement-Jacoco-to-generate-test-code-coverage-reports

The Jacoco test report is not getting generated. The console output says

`jacocotestReport is SKIPPED`

Executed from cmd line  --> `gwb test jacocoTestReport`

Output says `jacocotestReport is SKIPPED` as follows

```
:modules:configuration:test UP-TO-DATE
:modules:configuration:jacocoTestReport SKIPPED
```

We do have a few GUnit test cases under **gtest**.

When executed from cmd line --> `gwb test`

it always reports

```
:modules:configuration:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:modules:configuration:test UP-TO-DATE
```

How do you trigger GUnit test cases in version 9.x ?
How do you generate the Jacoco test report?

Comment: I took a brief look at the CC 9.0.5 documentation and didn't see much on how to force the "gwb test" command to start from scratch. Maybe try "gwb clean" and then "gwb test" and see what that does. Sorry I could not be of more help.